# Using genealogytree database entries as keys in l3prop property lists

Tags: genealogytree, l3prop

I'm trying to look up some of the data in a genealogy tree in an l3prop property list and do special stuff depending on what's in it.

In this MWE it is pared down to something not really useful, but hopefully it's clear what I'm trying to achieve. The "uuid" values of people are used to put something before their names. In the "Testing" part I test explicitly with the strings `berta` and `child` and the values I have stored there are seen. In the tree I don't understand how to do similar look-ups using the value of \gtrDBuuid`. I only get "Not" indicating it wasn't found. I've tried different signatures, but I am very unaccustomed to L3 and haven't succeeded.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \my_properties
\int_new:N \my_counter
\prop_put:NnV \my_properties { berta } \my_counter
\int_incr:N \my_counter
\prop_put:NnV \my_properties { child } \my_counter

% Testing:
\prop_if_in:NnTF \my_properties {berta} {Found} {Not}

\tl_new:N \thisval
\prop_get:NnN \my_properties {child} \thisval
\par Child~has~\thisval


\newcommand\testsomething{%
  \prop_if_in:NnTF \my_properties {\gtrDBuuid} {There} {Not}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\bigskip

\begin{genealogypicture}
  [
  template=database portrait,
  name code={\testsomething\quad \gtrDBname},
  ]
  child{
    g{male,name=Hans Test,
      uuid=hans,
    }
    p{female,name=Berta,
      uuid=berta,
    }
    c{name=Unknown,
      uuid=child,
    }
  }
\end{genealogypicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not directly relevant to the question, but please aim to use the general naming approach for `expl3`: there's a reason we have that structure. So for example I'd call the properties `\l_pst_data_prop` or similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In

```latex
\prop_if_in:NnTF \my_properties {\gtrDBuuid} {There} {Not}
```

you are looking for the string `\gtrDBuuid` in the property list. Instead, you want to look for the value currently stored in `\gtrDBuuid`:

```latex
\prop_if_in:NVTF \my_properties \gtrDBuuid {There} {Not}
```

Comment: Thank you! I could have sworn that was one of the options I had tried, but so much for that...